# AWS Lambda not invoked when using 'Event' invocation type

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I have 2 lambdas, `test1` which invokes `test2`. I want to invoke `test2` asynchronously with the "fire and forget" mentality.

Below is the code for both lambdas. When I set the `InvocationType` to `RequestResponse`, the function gets invoked and there is a log in CloudWatch. When I change the `InvocationType` to `Event`, there is no record in CloudWatch of the function being invoked.

test1:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const params = {
        'FunctionName': 'test2',
        'InvocationType': 'Event',
        'Payload': JSON.stringify('Hello')
    };

    const response = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
    return response;
};
```

test2:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    return 'Success';
};
```

The IAM policy includes invoke permissions (otherwise the `RequestResponse` type wouldn't work either). I've also read about [limits on the size of the args you can pass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), but in this case I'm only passing "Hello"...what gives?

EDIT: I should also add that in every case I get a response code of 202, which indicates a successful invoke, I just see no evidence of the function being executed in the logs.

EDIT 2: I've added `await` to the end of `test1`, but still do not see any indication that test2 was invoked in CloudWatch.

Comment: can you try using `invokeAsync` instead?

Comment: with `invokeAsync` you don't need to provide the `InvocationType` argument, so we can try to rule it out.

Comment: [`invokeAsync ` is deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_InvokeAsync.html). The docs say to use `invoke` with `Event` as the `InvocationType`

Comment: I know. Just trying to catch some unidentified bug since your code looks good. I have used that code myself and it worked fine (don't have the source code anymore, but I am sure it was exactly the same)

Comment: using `invokeAsync` results in the same behavior - no CloudWatch logs

Comment: Can you just `await` on your promise when invoking it Asynchronously? `await lambda.invoke(params).promise()`

Comment: Nope, same result :( As an aside, won't `await`ing the promise result in waiting for the 2nd lambda to finish?

Comment: No, because it would only wait until it executed the call to the other function successfully (internally, I think it sends the payload to a SQS queue and that Lambda picks it up afterwards), so, essentially, you'd only be waiting the message to be put in SQS

Answer (score 5):

I think there is just `await` missing:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const params = {
        'FunctionName': 'test2',
        'InvocationType': 'Event',
        'Payload': JSON.stringify('Hello')
    };

    await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
};
```

Without `await` a promise from `lambda.invoke(params).promise()` exites the lambda execution without resolving that promise.

Because the lambda is called asynchronously there is no result returned.

You can check the CloudWatch log of the `test2` lambda to see if has been invoked.